# Javascript is adding active class but not remove when click other button

Tags: javascript

```js
function grid_view() {
    grid_view_result();
    grid_view_button();
    
}

function grid_view_active() {
    if (document.getElementById("grid_view").className == "fa fa-th-large m-l-5") {
        document.getElementById("grid_view").className = "fa fa-th-large m-l-5 active";

    }
}
function grid_view_inactive() {
    if (document.getElementById("grid_view").className == "fa fa-th-large m-l-5 active") {
        document.getElementById("grid_view").className = "fa fa-th-large m-l-5";

    }
}

function grid_view_button() {
    if (document.getElementById("cooking_result").className == "recipes grid") {
        grid_view_active();
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("cooking_result").className = "recipes list") {
        grid_view_inactive();
        return;
    }
}

function grid_view_result() {
    if (document.getElementById("cooking_result").className == "recipes list") {
        document.getElementById("cooking_result").className = "recipes grid";
        
    }
}




function list_view() {
    list_view_result();
    list_view_button();
    
}

function list_view_active() {
    if (document.getElementById("list_view").className == "fa fa-th-list m-l-5") {
        document.getElementById("list_view").className = "fa fa-th-list m-l-5 active";

    }
}
function list_view_inactive() {
    if (document.getElementById("list_view").className == "fa fa-th-list m-l-5 active") {
        document.getElementById("list_view").className = "fa fa-th-list m-l-5";

    }
}

function list_view_button() {
    if (document.getElementById("cooking_result").className == "recipes list") {
        list_view_active();
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("cooking_result").className = "recipes grid") {
        list_view_inactive();
        return;
    }
}

function list_view_result() {
    if (document.getElementById("cooking_result").className == "recipes grid") {
        document.getElementById("cooking_result").className = "recipes list";
        
    }
}
```

```css
.active{text-decoration:underline;}
.recipes.grid li{float:left;width:50%;height:50px;background:red;}
.recipes li:nth-child(2){background:blue !important;}
.recipes.list li{float:left;width:100%;height:50px;background:red;}
```

```html
<i id="grid_view" onclick="grid_view();" class="fa fa-th-large m-l-5">Grid</i>
<i id="list_view" onclick="list_view();" class="fa fa-th-list m-l-5">List</i>
<ul id="cooking_result" class="recipes grid">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

I can add class="active" to i tag but I can't remove when I click to other i tag. May you help me to fix it?
Also, If possible, may you simplify to javascript? I think it's too long for this functionality :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tidied up solution.

The main changes I've made:

1. I've fixed the `underline` disappear/reappear issue, using `classList.toggle`;
2. I've shortened the `.js` quite a lot;
3. I've added a cosmetic change to the CSS, using `pointer:`
4. I've removed the inline `.js` events from the HTMLand made the `.js` unobtrusive

*Please ask questions in the comments below if there is anything that doesn't immediately seem clear to you.*

```js
var gridView = document.getElementById("grid_view");
var listView = document.getElementById("list_view");

function grid_view() {
 var cookingResult = document.getElementById("cooking_result");
 var gridView = document.getElementById("grid_view");
 var listView = document.getElementById("list_view");

    if (cookingResult.className === "recipes list") {
        cookingResult.className = "recipes grid";
        gridView.classList.toggle('active');
        listView.classList.toggle('active');
    }

}


function list_view() {
 var cookingResult = document.getElementById("cooking_result");
 var gridView = document.getElementById("grid_view");
 var listView = document.getElementById("list_view");

    if (cookingResult.className === "recipes grid") {
        cookingResult.className = "recipes list";
        gridView.classList.toggle('active');
        listView.classList.toggle('active');    
    }
    
}

gridView.addEventListener('click',grid_view,false);
listView.addEventListener('click',list_view,false);
```

```css
.active {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.recipes.grid li {
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 50px;
background: red;
}

.recipes.list li {
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: red;
}

.recipes li:nth-of-type(2) {
background: blue;
}

#grid_view, #list_view {
cursor: pointer;
}

#grid_view.active, #list_view.active {
cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<i id="grid_view" class="fa fa-th-large m-l-5 active">Grid</i>
<i id="list_view" class="fa fa-th-list m-l-5">List</i>
<ul id="cooking_result" class="recipes grid">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```